# Query to Delete Rows where Columns Match or are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with several columns. I need to compare a few of those columns to each other and delete the rows where they match each other or are NULL. To put it differently, I need to leave the rows only where there are differences other than NULL. (If it matters, I'll run this several times against tables with a different number of columns being compared, sometimes very many columns, so things queries that focus on there only being three columns will not work.)

So, if my table is:

```
ID  TITLE   VALUE_1 VALUE_2 VALUE_3
1   One     AAA     NULL    NULL
2   Two     NULL    AAA     AAA
3   Three   AAA     AAA     AAA
4   Four    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   Five    AAA     BBB     CCC
6   Six     AAA     BBB     NULL
7   Seven   NULL    DDD     EEE
8   Eight   AAA     AAA     BBB
```

After running the query, I'd want to have

```
ID  TITLE   VALUE_1 VALUE_2 VALUE_3
5   Five    AAA     BBB     CCC
6   Six     AAA     BBB     NULL
7   Seven   NULL    DDD     EEE
8   Eight   AAA     AAA     BBB
```

Comment: This would be a LOT simpler if your data was normalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table
where v1 <> v2 or v1 <> v3 or v2 <> v3
```

This will return rows where there will be `TRUE` for any of pair. So surrounding that predicate with `NOT IN` will give desired set to delete:

```
delete t where id not in(select id from t where v1 <> v2 or v1 <> v3 or v2 <> v3)
```

Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea7172/8

Comment: This is great! It works perfectly. Thank you! I guess this is a stupid question, but can you please explain why that select does not return the first two rows? In both rows, v1 <> v2 ('aaa' is not NULL), but those are not returned by the select, and therefore not deleted. Again, to be clear, this is exactly what I want, I'm just trying to understand how it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, the select will pick only rows where predicate in where clause is evaluated to true. If it evaluestes to false or unknown(unknown will be if there is null on at least one side) the row will be filtered out. For example row 1.  Aaa <> null or aaa <> null or null <> null => unknown or unknown or unknown => unknown. It will be filtered out. For row 7.  Null <> ddd or null <> eee or ddd <> eee => unknown or unknown or true => true. So row 7 will not be filtered out, it will be in resultset

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, but that's much clearer. Thanks again for the query and the explanation.

Comment: I.e. this is 3 valued logic. Predicate can evaluate to 3 values: true, false, unknown. `v1 <> v2 or v1 <> v3 or v2 <> v3` this is predicate. Where will filter the rows where that predicate evaluates to only TRUE.  a = a evaluates to true. a = b evaluates to false. a = null evaluates to unknown. null = null evaluates to unknown. a <> a evaluates to false. a <> b evaluates to true. a <> null evaluates to unknown. null <> null evaluates to unknown.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Delete from tablename 
      where (Value_1 is Null And value_2 is null) 
             or (Value_2 is Null And value_3 is null)
             or (Value_1 is Null And value_3 is null)
             or (Value_1 = value_2)
             or (Value_1 = value_3)
             or (Value_3 = value_2)
```

This should be able to delete if there are two columns of null, or any two column matching. There is no string compare function in sql server in case you are wondering

Comment: I don't think this gives him what he's wanting.  A null can be present in one or more columns, he just wants to delete the row if there are two columns that are NOT null that have the same data.

Comment: I think the whole question can be summed up as, "I need to leave the rows only where there are differences other than NULL", however that conflicts with why he deleted row 1, so I think he wants to delete any row where any two columns are equal, whether NULL or not...

Comment: @TonyHinkle Yes, that's correct, I need to leave only rows where there are differences other than NULL. Maybe I'm missing something, but row 1 has AAA, NULL, NULL, so it's deleted, because there are no differences other than NULL.

Comment: did you try my code? it should work fine. let me know.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to check it (in a meeting) but thanks! Looking at it though, it looks like it would delete, for example, if Value_1 = 'AAA' and Value_2 = 'BBB', and Value_3 = 'BBB', as that would meet the last condition. And I want to keep that. I want to keep all rows that are different other than NULL.

Comment: your sample output suggest something different though. let me know after your meeting

Comment: I tested your query. That will delete rows where any two are NULL. In the example above, that would be ok, but I sometimes have more, sometimes many more, than three columns I'm comparing. I could make that work, by adding more fields to the list. 

However, it also will delete when none of them are null, and two of the three fields are the same, so it does not meet the condition of "leave the rows where there are differences other than null."

Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ISNULL` Like this in your `DELETE` statement

`Where IsNull (Value_1, 'SomeValueThatWillNeverBeInTheTable') = IsNull (Value_2, 'SomeValueThatWillNeverBeInTheTable')`